# Excel, apply conditional formatting to new entries automatically

Tags: excel

i am working on excel and trying to apply conditional formatting based on formula =AND(C2<>"",C2

and is currently applied to

=$C$2:$C$1336

how can i apply this to new entries as well

Comment: Ctrl-C to copy cell, the Paste Special -> Formatting.

Comment: New entry means `C1337, C1338 ...` and so on?

Comment: yes you got it right @harun24hr

Comment: @FDavidov it didnt work can you please suggest any solution

Comment: Edit the conditional format of the source cell and you will see that the conditional format includes `$` within the reference to the cell. Simply remove these signs, apply the change, and try copying and paste-special again.

Comment: @YasirKhalid Your formula in not completed. `=AND(C2<>"",C2` can you put complete formula.

Comment: @YasirKhalid 1 minute! Why not your applying to full column? Apply to full column, then it will automatically detect new entries as well.